# How to detect end of picture download in AsyncImage in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

i'm writting a simple appliaction like this one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage


class Application(App):

    def build(self):
        box_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        img = AsyncImage(
            source='http://pl.python.org/forum/Smileys/default/cheesy.gif')

        box_layout.add_widget(img)
        return box_layout

    def __on_image_loaded(self):
        print('Very importatn stuff executed afer image has been downloaded by img widget.')

app = Application()
app.run()
```

How can I detect that AsyncImage widget ended downloading picture from given URL?

Alternatively I can write downloading thread by myself and use Image widget but in this case what could I do to load raw bytes from memory to Image widget to display them as a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `img._coreimage.bind(on_load=self.on_image_loaded)`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage


class Application(App):

    def build(self):
        box_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        img = AsyncImage(source='http://pl.python.org/forum/Smileys/default/cheesy.gif')
        img._coreimage.bind(on_load=self.on_image_loaded)

        box_layout.add_widget(img)
        return box_layout

    def on_image_loaded(self, *args):
        print('Very importatn stuff executed afer image has been downloaded by img widget.')

app = Application()
app.run()
```